# Generating iTunes podcast feed with WCF

Tags: wcf, itunes, feed, podcast

How do you make an iTunes podcast feed with WCF? Or do you know of a complete example that actually works?

I've reached the point where I corrected all errors and warnings[1] marked by feedvalidator.org and also included all the iTunes custom tags I could and iTunes still claims it's a broken feed (obviously giving no useful information about it).

[1] I haven't solved two warnings: one is that the address of the podcast is not consistent, because I'm running it on localhost, and the other that I am using namespaces for the atom embedded tags when producing an RSS, for which there's no work around using WCF.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this user was able to get it working: [How do you add another namespace to WCF SyndicationFeed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1375119/how-do-you-add-another-namespace-to-wcf-syndicationfeed)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Which I just noticed was posted by you as well, so are you still having trouble or is this working now?

Answer (score -2):

I believe WCF is a communications framework that uses SOAP, and is meant for something more like Web Services, rather than hosting an XML file. Even if it is possible, WCF is probably not the right way to do what you're trying to do.

Edit: Uninformed opinions do not make good answers. Forget I said anything!

Comment: WCF should be more than capable of this. Why do you think this problem is as simple as "hosting an XML file"?